# Office 365 security groups with SharePoint Permissions

Tags: permissions, office-365, team-sites

I have created departments for example:

- Business Developement
- CAD
- HR

Now I have been reading that I should be adding my Office 365 security groups inside my SharePoint groups.

For example:

Do I need to create three Office 365 security groups and add my users to these groups:

- SharePoint - Business Development Visitors
- SharePoint - Business Development Edit
- SharePoint - Business Development Owner

[image]

Then add the groups above to the SharePoint groups with the site permission section?

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble using security groups as the source of sharepoint permissions. Does not seem to actually invite the users in the groups. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/258730/security-group-invite-external-users-to-sharepoint-site-generating-invite-email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. It is best practice to create security groups and assign these groups rights in SharePoint, for once the security groups have been correctly configured there is no need to return and fiddle with SharePoint securities if new users get added for example.

Read more here: [Using Office 365 security groups with SharePoint Online](http://blog.ciaops.com/2013/02/using-office-365-security-groups-with.html)